# Sort string's characters into alphabetic order

Tags: c++, strings, sorting

Any improvements that I can make with this code?
Also, is there another way to convert a vector to a string variable without using a for ranged-based loop? From the posts I've seen for converting, I only saw printing the vector instead of returning a string.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

std::string AlphabetSoup(string str) {
std::vector<char>letters;

 istringstream iss(str);

 copy(istream_iterator<char>(iss),
        istream_iterator<char>(),
        back_inserter(letters));

 std::sort(letters.begin(),letters.end());

 //Regrouping the characters into a string
 std::string orderedString;
 for(auto element : letters)
 {
     orderedString += element;
 }

 return orderedString;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### [Don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/5416291)

You don't need a stringstream or an istringstream or a vector for this. `std::sort` can be performed on a string directly. An std::string_view can be used to avoid copying (more on this later)

---

There seems to be 3 options how to make this work best. If you don't care about chewing up your original string you can perform the operations on it directly without ever copying anything. Here you will pass by reference:

```
std::string& AlphabetSoup(std::string& str) {
   std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
   str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());

 return str; // or omit this and change the return value to void
}
```

You can also pass by value which will copy your string and leave the original intact:

```
std::string AlphabetSoup(std::string str) {
   std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
   str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());

 return str;
}
```

Or you can pass in as a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) which will not copy.

```
std::string AlphabetSoup(std::string_view str) {
   std::string s(str);
   std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
   s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());
   return s;
}
```

---

The method I used to remove the spaces is known as the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). The character specified in the `remove()` function is moved to the end of the range (provided as parameters) where they can be efficiently erased. There are faster iterators on sorted sets that can speed things up as @TobySpeight pointed out but I haven't used them. (Namely `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`)

---

Consider providing test cases and output. This too will help reviewers and make it more likely for you to get solid answers.

Comment: Your revised code doesn't do the same thing as the original. By using the stringstream and stream iterators, the original strips spaces. Whether that is intentional or not... who knows?

Comment: Is it better to make a copy of str or just use the str?

Comment: If you don't want to modify the original string, you can still use something like the second version, but pass `str` by value (generally a good plan for anything you intend to copy).

Comment: You might be able to make a more efficient space-removal on the sorted string, using binary search (`std::lower_bound()` and `std::upper_bound()`) to find the first and last element to erase.

Comment: @austingae Depends on your use case. If you need the original string for any reason ever again definately don't chew it up.

Answer (score 6):

Well, [never use `using namespace something_humungeous_and_growing_like_std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), because there might be conflicts, and silent changes of semantics.

Next, avoid shuffling data around. There's no need to create any extra-copies.

Third, first efficiently discard the dross, then refine the raw ore. Refining the dross too is wasted effort.

```
std::string AlphabetSoup(std::string s) noexcept {
    auto unwanted = [](char c){ return std::isspace((unsigned char)c); };
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), unwanted), s.end());
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should first be sure what exactly you mean by the word "character". When used in C++, it means "byte" and has nothing to do with any writing system. And that in turn means that "ä" can be 1 or 2 or 3 "characters” long.

Comment: Also, decide on exactly what you mean by "alphabetic order" - it's not necessarily code-point order.

Comment: @TobySpeight All the idiosyncracies of scripts old and new, limitations of (modern) computers, and desire for a single simple uniform way to handle all the mess: That's Unicode, the many-faceted.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question: there *is* a simpler method to convert between strings and vectors of characters.  Both can be constructed from a pair of iterators:

```
std::string s{"some string"};
std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());
std::string s2(v.begin(), v.end());
assert(s == s2);
```

However, in most cases this conversion is unnecessary, as `std::string` provides all the functionality of `std::vector<char>` already (as demonstrated in the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

There is of course a much faster sorting for `char`, namely **counting sort**. This is only O(n) instead of O(n log n):

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>

std::string AlphabetSoup(const std::string& text) {
    std::array<std::size_t, UCHAR_MAX> count{};

    for (unsigned char letter : text) {
        ++count[letter];
    }

    std::vector<char> v;
    v.reserve(text.size());

    char letter { 0 };
    for (int cnt : count) {
        v.insert(v.end(), cnt, letter++);
    }
    return {v.begin(), v.end()};
}
```

Comment: @TobySpeight you are totally right.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of fixing some of the problems with your code - in particular, the uninitialized `std::array` which caused it to crash for me.  Note also that you could have made `v` a `std::string`, so no need for vectors.

Comment: Oh, and you could simply use `v.append(cnt, letter++)` instead of the `insert`, once you're using `std::string` there.

Comment: I disagree that you call it a radix sort, radix uses counting (or bucket) sort repeatedly to do its sort.In this case each bucket is a single value and not a range so it is a counting sort in this case. Other than that it nicely converts my concept code to working code, thanks.